# JQuery Mobile Percentage Height Issue

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-mobile, cordova

I'm trying to fix the height as a percentage of a header element in JQuery Mobile on my login page.

```
#login .ui-header
{
height: 62%;
}
```

The height of the parent element is 615px on my test device; As shown in this screenshot.

http://grab.by/nEKK

However my header is only given a height of 241px?

Any help would be much appreciated

Comment: What happens when you use height of 100%?

Comment: Appears to stay the same whatever the %.

Comment: I don't see #login or .ui-header in your screenshot. You should post parent divs as well

Comment: height: 62% !important;

Answer (score 0):

Do you want height in pixel or percentage? It seems only padding is working. Adjust with the padding instead of height?

See DEMO http://jsfiddle.net/yeyene/Rdfxs/1/

```
#login #my_header{
    padding: 20% 0 !important;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your replies guys. The !important didnt seem to fix the issue.

In the end i set my page height separately as so...

```
$(function() {
$('#login').css({'height':windowHeight });
});
```

This seemed to override whatever jquery mobile was doing and the percentages then fixed themselves.